# Convert SQL statement into JPA CriteriaBuilder query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteriaquery

I need to convert this SQL statement into a JPA CriteriaBuilder query/
The problem I have is with the LEFT JOIN and the Subquery and the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
  candi.*, 
  MAX(ponderation.score) score 
FROM 
  candy.candidate candi 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      candidate_id, 
      CASE 
        WHEN profile_id = 941 and skill_type_id = 970 THEN 10 
        WHEN profile_id = 941 and skill_type_id = 972 THEN 3 
        ELSE null
      END score 
    FROM 
      candy.j_candidate_job_profile
  ) as ponderation ON candi.id = ponderation.candidate_id 
WHERE 
  ponderation.score IS NOT null 
GROUP BY 
  candi.id 
ORDER BY 
  candi.id
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Thanks I edited the post!

Comment: What have you tried so far?